# How to make Tomcat8 return 503 status code?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, server.xml

I have an application which process `1` request in `~100ms`. What I intend to do is return `503(service unavailable)` for requests when I'm getting more requests than I can handle. My `server.xml` for Connector component in tomcat8 looks like this

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                   connectionTimeout="200"
                   URIEncoding="UTF-8"
                   redirectPort="8443"
                   maxThreads="200"
                   acceptCount="0"
                   maxConnections="200"
/>
```

Going by the definition provided in the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes), my `acceptCount` component is the queue when all my `maxThreads` are processing(being used). `maxConnections` is the number of connections server will accept or process at any given time. I'm intending on processing only `200` requests at a single moment. The load testing I'm doing is by apache benchmark with the following config. `ab -l  -n 1000 -c 1000 -s 100`, the overall latency increases from `100ms` to `2000+ms` but still **ALL** my requests are being processed. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT1**: As suggestied by dit I ran it with `20000` requests and now I'm receiving `apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)` which as mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/146605/understanding-this-error-apr-socket-recv-connection-reset-by-peer-104) suggests that it is due to config for the tomcat, so, thats a plus. However, Why is this error being sent and not an HTTP4XX or 503 response?

**EDIT2**: I'll be trying the method as mentioned in the answer I wrote.

**EDIT3**: So to obtain the information on how many Tomcat threads are busy and how many connections are currentyl established I am enabling JMX on Tomcat. I retrieve the mbeans info for tomcat

Comment: be sure, tomcat will do it automatically if it is necessary.

Comment: Isnt that supposed to be handled as HTTP 429 or HTTP 408 ?

Comment: @dit That's the issue, I'm confused as to why tomcat is not sending any error response.

Comment: @RajaAnbazhaganI'm fine with any error response, as long there is one. Right now I'm not receiving any.

Comment: send about 5T -10T requests simultaneously and you will see ;)

Comment: @dit ps the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](http://techblog.netflix.com/2015/07/tuning-tomcat-for-high-throughput-fail.html) suggests that I'll have to myself monitor the number of threads working and If Im overloaded and send the response accordingly.

> Track the number of active concurrent requests in memory
>   and use it for fast failing. If the number of concurrent requests is
>   near the estimated active threads (8 in our example) then return an
>   http status code of 503. This will prevent too many worker threads
>   becoming busy because once the peak throughput is hit, any extra
>   threads which become active will be doing a very light weight job of
>   returning 503 and then be available for further processing.

`apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)` will be sent If I'm not handling the requests myself.